# Passing data to a nested template not working as expected

Tags: http, parsing, go, nested, go-templates

I was trying to get a struct passed to a nested template in Go, using `html/template` and tried to achieve it using both `template.ParseFiles` and `template.ParseGlob`, but it is not working as per my expectation because my understanding is not clear.

My template code for the file `header.html` is

```
{{define "header"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> SiteAdmin - {{.User}}</title>
</head>
{{end}}
```

and for the file `admin.html` is

```
{{template "header"}}
<body>
"User is {{.User}}"
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the `Execute` method on the type *Template as

```
type Admin struct {
    User string
}


data := new(Admin)
data.User = "Guest"
tpl, err := template.ParseGlob("views/templates/admin/*.html")
CheckForErr(err)
err = tpl.Execute(w, data)
CheckForErr(err)
```

With the above code, I can pass around the struct data to `admin.html`, and it shows `User is Guest` in the browser. But if I try to pass it to any of the nested templates, it wouldn't. The title of the page still shows as `SiteAdmin -` and not `SiteAdmin - Guest`. The `User` data from the struct is visible only if I call it as `{{.User}}` inside the `admin.html` file, and any reference to it in the nested templates turns out to be not passed. Is this something achievable?

Thank you all.

Comment: Probably you need to use `{{ template "header" . }}` (note the `.`)

Comment: Wow, Thank you @leafbebop it worked. Could you please post it as an answer? I will accept it. On a separate note, was it mentioned in the documentation? I wanted to know where should I have been looking for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `{{ template "header" . }}`. As the document in [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) say:

> {{template "name" pipeline}}
>
> The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
>       to the value of the pipeline.

In this case, the pipeline you passed into is `.`, which reffers to the whole `data`.

It is somehow unconvenient that documents of `html/template` is mostly in `text/template`.